# Is it OK to store the result from vector.size() into variable of type int?

Tags: c++

Is it OK to store the result from vector.size() into variable of type int?

For example, I get warning for this:

```
int n = a.size();
```

Is it OK to do this:

```
int n = (int)a.size();
```

or should I use a variable n of a different type?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not generally OK because the return type of `size()` can easily have values that are too large to store in an `int`. You should use a variable of the same type as the return type of `size()` for that particular `vector`. This is easily achieved with `auto`:

```
auto n = a.size();
```

If you don't have c++11 support, then you can use the `vector`'s `size_type`:

```
std::vector<TheType>::size_type n = a.size();
```

where `a` is an `std::vector<TheType>`.

Comment: The latter is quite a mouthful. What makes it worth it?

Comment: @delnan It is necessary in the absence of C++11, but of course it can be aleviated with a `typedef`.

Comment: @delnan Are you downvoting both of us?

Comment: I am not downvoting either of you. And to be more precise, I'd like to know how this is better than `size_t` or another "easier", more standard type.

Comment: @delnan It's better because the declaration of `vector::size()` determines it to be `vector<T>::size_type`, which may not be `size_t`.

Comment: @delnan I don't think `size_type` is *guaranteed* to be the same as `size_t`. But I have never seen an implementation where it is something different.

Comment: @juanchopanza - `vector<T, Alloc>::size_t` is a synonym for `Alloc::size_type`; if you use the standard allocator (as in `vector<int>`, that's required to be `std::size_t`. If you use a custom allocator it can be something else.

Comment: If I understood correctly, I can't be wrong by using auto? And not even bother with thinking about size_t or size_type?

Comment: @user2381422 Correct. `auto` will give you the type being returned by that particular `vector`. It saves you a lot of typing and reduces scope for error in generic code.

Answer (score 8):

No, it's not OK. Use

```
std::vector<T>::size_type n = a.size();
```

or if you are less pedantic:

```
size_t n = a.size();
```

Comment: Using auto would be much better, agree?

Comment: @user2381422 If you know that so well, then why are you asking? Troll.

Comment: I don't know, from what I read what others posted I am just asking you what you think?

Comment: @H2CO3 If you like to do me a favor internalize comity and countenance (at least a little). Your formulations and the way you emphasize certain things suggest that you get indignant quite easy. (I won't discuss on that; just think about it.) I'm not placing any downvotes on this post since it (at least) slaps down a correct answer. (Eventhough, I think it lacks illuminating explanations, which I tend to consider favourable when answering such basic questions.)

Comment: @Pixelchemist You must be right in that the other answer is better - I assume that it's why it has got more upvotes.

Answer (score 5):

It's okay if you're sure that the number of elements will fit in an `int`.